# Image getting stretched while making uiimage in oval shape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using following code to make an image oval shape.

```
 UIImage * fooImage = image;

CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 291, 130);

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size,NO,0.0);
// create a bezier path defining rounded corners
UIBezierPath * path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(img_blank.frame), CGRectGetHeight(img_blank.frame))];

// use this path for clipping in the implicit context
[path addClip];
// draw the image into the implicit context
[fooImage drawInRect:imageRect];
// save the clipped image from the implicit context into an image
UIImage *maskedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
       img_blank.image=maskedImage;
```

Here `image_blank` is the UIImage which I am using, if image with greater width and less height comes then it will not strech. If I change the values, I won't get an oval shape that fits my `UIImageview(img_blank)`.

Comment: Try to set `contentMode` of your `img_blank` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`, which will display your image as it's.

Comment: i already tried that didn't work

Comment: Then, before drawing your image to the frame of the oval, try to scale and crop your image to the size of the oval, and make sure your image view's frame size is same as image's size. Good Luck!

Comment: Scaling images getting streched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is that your rect size and your image size don't match.

When you:
     [fooImage drawInRect:imageRect];

the image will be drawn skewed into that rectangle, which you've defined as `CGRectMake(0, 0, 291, 130);`

To get it to work, you need to create a second rectangle that expands the oval's rectangle to match the image'a width/height ratio. You can then use this second rectangle to draw the image so that the image will aspect-fill the oval.

This is some pseudo code that I've used in the past for similar problems:

```
// get the size of the image that we want to scale
CGSize imageSize = imageToDraw.size;
// get the size of the canvas we're trying to fill
CGSize canvasSize = imageRect.size;
// we need to see how the ratio of image width & height compare to the canvas
CGFloat horizontalRatio = canvasSize.width / imageSize.width;
CGFloat verticalRatio = canvasSize.height / imageSize.height;
// pick the ratio that requires the most scaling
CGFloat ratio = MAX(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio); //AspectFill
// calculate the size that we should draw the image so that it could fill
// the entire canvas with an aspect-fill rule
CGSize aspectFillSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize.width * ratio, imageSize.height * ratio);

// now draw the image, centering it and filling the canvas
[imageToDraw drawInRect:CGRectMake((canvasSize.width-aspectFillSize.width)/2,
                                           (canvasSize.height-aspectFillSize.height)/2,
                                            aspectFillSize.width,
                                            aspectFillSize.height)];
```

Comment: The issue is i can't change my rect size.It will cause many problems.Can we scale an image properly to my rect size?

Comment: That's what this code snippet does. It keeps your oval rect the same, but uses a different rect when drawing the image into it so that the image aspect fills the original oval. This allows any sized image to fill any other sized oval and maintain its aspect ratio.